# Converting large, complex XML documents to HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, parsing

I am working on a project to create a parser that takes textbooks stored in XML and convert them to HTML with PHP. This is for use with an online education service. I have spent a good amount of time researching options for XML parsers in PHP. From what I can see I believe my best options are using DOMDocument or XMLReader (perhaps mixing it with SimpleXML).

The books are split up into separate files as Front, Units, Chapters and Back. This is provided from an external source so I have no control over the XML. That being said I have figured out that they are using [Syntext Serna Free](http://www.serna-xmleditor.com/) for building the XML documents.

So the books are named by ISBN# and the files follow the format 1234567890_ch01.xml. This is an example of the XML documents. This is highly condensed for readability as the actual documents are 700-1000 lines per document with about 25 documents per textbook.

```
<frontmatter id="1234567890_001_000003" page-num="i" filename="1234567890_001_fm01.xml" sourcefilename="prelims.pdf">
    <titleinfo id="1234567890_001_000004" page-num="i">
        <title id="1234567890_001_000005" page-num="i">I'm a Book Title</title>
        <subtitle id="1234567890_001_000006" page-num="i">I'm a subtitle</subtitle>
    </titleinfo>
    <creditinfo id="1234567890_001_000007" page-num="i">
        <author id="1234567890_001_000008" page-num="i">
            <name><emph type="bold">Senior Author</emph>
                <fname><emph type="bold">Bob</emph></fname>
                <lname><emph type="bold">Loblaw</emph></lname>
            </name>
            <organizationname>District School Board</organizationname>
        </author>
        <author id="1234567890_001_000009" page-num="i">
            <name><emph type="bold">Authors</emph>
                <fname><emph type="bold">Spongebob</emph></fname>
                <lname><emph type="bold">Squarepants</emph></lname>
            </name>
            <organizationname>District School Board</organizationname>
        </author>
    </creditinfo>
</frontmatter>
```

So this is the basic idea of the layout. Of course there is a ton more to it but essentially its all sorted by parent tags. I'm thinking what my strategy will be is to make a list of the parent tags, read those using a SAX parser and turn the children into SimpleXML objects for ease of use. Essentially keeping the same XML structure but wrapping it in HTML elements and putting the XML element name as the class or id name as well as translating the XML attributes straight to HTML attributes.

Phew. Ok, so my question is ... does anyone have some knowledge or experience they can share for parsing XML documents of this size/complexity and what are the recommended strategies for something of this scale?

Comment: Have you considered using XSLT? It's an XML based language used to transform XML documents into other formats and I think it could suit this problem quite nicely.

Comment: @JaniHartikainen one of the factors is that it must be HTML that can be then styled with CSS. There are already existing CSS on the pages that this HTML will be a part of and older books that were parsed with an older C# parser that I am replacing with this PHP version. 

I am not that familiar with XSLT but it seems I would end up writing a LOT of structure code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely look into Jani Hartikainen's suggestion of XSLT. XSLT is an XML-based language for writing rules (called "stylesheets", but they're different from CSS stylesheets) that transform arbitrary XML documents (such as the input you're dealing with) into other formats, including HTML (transforming into HTML is so common that XSLT has some functions dedicated to it). PHP has a built-in XSLT processor.

It may be that the textbook publisher already has some XSLT stylesheets for transforming textbooks into HTML; you'd probably have to modify them somewhat for your specific needs, but that would be a lot easier and less error-prone than writing your own from scratch.